# What's this book about?

Tags: jewish-books

http://www.hebrewbooks.org/8769

My Rabbinic Hebrew is very poor and my wife was asking for a book on Niddah and other womanly things so i was looking for a book according to the Egyptian tradition. Does this book cover such things?

Comment: No. Your link is not on that subject. What language does your wife speak and read normally?

Comment: English. She has a Rebbetzin interested in going through the books with her and translating them with Hebrew.

Comment: An excellent book in English is Family Purity by Rabbi Fishel Jacobs. Your wife and her Rebbetzin could go over it together. Here's a link: http://www.judaica.com/family-purity.html

Comment: @YaacovDeane Is that book according to the Egyptian tradition?

Comment: @DoubleAA i'm fairly certain there isn't going to be a specific book on the issue, i'll probably just have her go through the sections of Nehar Misrayim that fall under Niddah. But sometimes the halakhoth there aren't encompassing of everything, just what specific Egyptian things are done

Comment: I agree with your assessment. This link is for a book dealing specifically with minhagei Mitzrayim and the only mention I spotted in regard to Niddah and Mikvah was about whether the custom permits warming the water prior to immersion. The book I recommended is a comprehensive and practical guide by a working posek in Israel today. It covers the laws in detail with sources explaining many different shitas. Here's the link:http://www.hebrewbooks.org/8878

Comment: I didn't see anything in the indexes for Sefer Ginat Veredim by Rabbi Avraham ben Mordechai HaLevi that were dealing with Hilchot niddah or taharat hamishpacha.Here's the link for Nahar Mitzrayim. Hilchot Niddah starts on page 190. http://www.hebrewbooks.org/34122

Comment: http://seforim.blogspot.com/2016/02/the-agunah-problem-part-2-wearing.html

Comment: @DoubleAA If you could translate the included sections mentioned in that post i would really appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The book you linked to is about **the laws of a rebellious wife**. The book was authored in Egypt and printed in Jerusalem.

Comment: Just to say it explicitly: that book is about dissolving broken marriages, and is not the one you want!